# How to work properly sending clean PR

Tags: git

I'm working using a branch for each feature/fix that I made in the project

we work on dev, usually i do the following

```
@master $ git checkout dev
@dev $ git pull --rebase
@dev $ git co -b new-feature
@new-feature $ git add & git commit -m "change I did..."
@new-feature $ git push origin new-feature
```

later I make the PR from new-feature to dev

For start a other feature

```
@new-feature $ git co -b other-feature
@other-feature $ git add . & git commit -m "change I did..." 
@other-feature $ git rebase --onto dev new-feature other-feature
@other-feature $ git push origin other-feature
```

later I make the PR from other-feature to dev

My problem is how i can have a branch with all previous features to continue the development process

Sometimes the I have a third feature that need changes from previous, example: add a new depedency in the package.json for a node project. I dont want add the same dependency again in that case which is the better way to start the new feature without start from dev but still sending a clear PR. Oviously the example can be more complex like a bugfix

Answer (score 0):

Cut a branch right from dev, with `git branch newbranch dev` and your new branch will have the previous state of your dev branch.

If other people are working on that dev branch and changes are made before you need to start a new feature, `git pull --rebase origin dev` onto a fresh branch that is behind the dev branch.

**Edit**

While that answers your question, I imagine it would be cleaner to regularly `rebase` from wherever your PR gets merged to.

Comment: I have a doubt I'll expand the question